# How to monitor pvc using grafana + prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-pvc

I'm trying configure this (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13646-kubernetes-persistent-volumes/?tab=revisions) dashboard to display information only for the pvc which contains "redis" in their names, does you have any ideas how to edit promql queries for that?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to replace variable `k8s_namespace` with `.*redis.*` in dashboard config?

Comment: @markalex Yes, but when I replace k8s_namespace with .*redis.* it does't work for some reason

Comment: Then you need [edit] question and describe what exactly you've done, what is not working, and how do you imagine it should work.

Comment: Additionally, select one of the panels that don't work, select `Explore (x)` in the menu and add a query, that will be displayed in the Metric browser to describe of question.

Comment: @markalex I just want to know how the queries for this dashboard should be changed so that it only  shows info for pvc's that contains redis in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_info{persistentvolumeclaim=~".*redis.*"}
```

If you meant the word "redis" contained in other fields, replace the "persistentvolumeclaim" value written in curly braces with:

-cluster

-container

-endpoint

-environment

-job

-namespace

-prometheus

-service

-storageclass

-volumename

https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/persistentvolumeclaim-metrics.md